# How to center an ImageView on the edge of a cardView?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I have a layout like this:

[image]

My xml for that layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context=".view.testviews.ProfileFragment"
android:background="@color/colorDarkGrey">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-50dp">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/user_image_placeholder"
                app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
                app:civ_border_width="2dp">
            </de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView>

        </FrameLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm trying to center the `circleImageView` on the edge of the `cardView`. But the top part of it is invisible. I looked up for similar questions, but they couldn't meet my requirements. How can I achieve this?

So I tried @PPartisan's solution, and it made it like this:

[image]

The code for that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context=".view.testviews.ProfileFragment"
android:background="@color/colorDarkGrey">
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp">
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:src="@drawable/user_image_placeholder"
        app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        >
    </de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make your `ImageView` a child of the `CardView`, as it will be clipped by its parent. Also, when considering XML, the drawing order is specified from top to bottom, which means that Views specified later in the XML will be drawn over any views that are specified earlier. This mean you should draw your `CardView` first, and then your `CircleImageView`. Your layout structure should therefore be:

```
<CardView.../>
<...CircleImageView.../>
```

I would also recommend you use  `CoordinatorLayout` as it will be simpler to use features like guidelines to correctly align your various views.

**Edit:** Thankyou Adinia for pointing out in the comments that it is also necessary to set an elevation on the image to ensure it draws on top.

Comment: I tried this, but that didn't work. Edited the question. Can you check it?

Comment: You just need to also add `android:elevation="2dp"` to your CircleImageView

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

So your layout becomes:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="80dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/titelbild280x280"
        />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```